# Webview can't load content via javascript on htc one x

Tags: android, webview, webkit

I have build an app which post data to my webservice. As response I will get the html code of the page. The real content of the page will be loaded with javascript.

While loading the content via javascript the webview stops loading I get this message:

Tag: webcore
Text: [webViewCore::webkitDraw] defer message ====

I can't find any explanation about this warning.

On any Nexus devices my solution works great but not on this htc device ...

Comment: I have find the solution ... htc webview can't handle relative paths for javascripts ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTC Devices with HTC Sence 4.0 can't handle relative paths for javascripts in a webview.

Changing to absolute paths will fix that problem.

Comment: are you sure about this .. i'm also getting same problem in my htc

Comment: @MrDyro I am also having the same issue can u tell me how i can change the relative paths to absolute paths?